# Prove Cesàro mean using the weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, cesaro-summable

Is it possible to prove that the [Cesàro mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) of a converging sequence is the limit of the sequence through probabilities using the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law) ? Has it ever been done ?

Answer (score 0):

The weak law of large numbers usually concerns the case where the initial sequence is divergent. So there is no chance to apply the LLN.

Comment: I don't really get it. What do you mean by saying it usually concerns that case ? In what way does it entail we can't apply it to this problem ?

Comment: @Minipipo1, because LLN usually speaks about a sequence of independent random variables. Such sequence can converge only to a deterministic limit. This virtually removes stochasticity from the LLN, almost transforming it to a deterministic result.